# pictures in carousel bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

guys! i have three pictures that i neeed to put in my bootstrap carousel. but i can t do this, they are not full on the screen. how can i change their  size to put fully? there are there
[1](https://www.google.com.ua/search?dcr=0&biw=1280&bih=893&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=team%20spirit%20csgo&oq=team%20spirit%20csgo&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i13k1j0i10i24k1.6808.9785.0.9999.11.9.2.0.0.0.133.804.0j7.7.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..2.7.579...0j0i67k1j0i24k1.0.MKrQgm7RSK8#imgrc=RncnR_J2xNlWnM:)

[2](https://www.google.com.ua/search?dcr=0&biw=1280&bih=893&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=team%20spirit%20csgo&oq=team%20spirit%20csgo&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i13k1j0i10i24k1.6808.9785.0.9999.11.9.2.0.0.0.133.804.0j7.7.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..2.7.579...0j0i67k1j0i24k1.0.MKrQgm7RSK8#imgrc=FkjjoEZicJnCEM:)

[3](https://www.google.com.ua/search?dcr=0&biw=1280&bih=893&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=team%20spirit%20csgo&oq=team%20spirit%20csgo&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i13k1j0i10i24k1.6808.9785.0.9999.11.9.2.0.0.0.133.804.0j7.7.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..2.7.579...0j0i67k1j0i24k1.0.MKrQgm7RSK8#imgrc=cKDkuwOgMHmmwM:)

Comment: Please post the html and css you are using.

Comment: i need a encoding, not a code

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read
[what this site is about](https://stackoverflow.com/about) and 
"[How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)" 
before asking a question.

Answer (score -1):

I am not 100% sure what you are trying to achieve but I guess you´re looking for:

```
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
```

If styles aren´t the ones you´re looking for, specify your question.

Comment: i need in an encoding of picture i think. this doesn t work